# Chrome developer tool Array length

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

Why chrome developer tool showing 0 array length (first line Array[0]) even if there are total 9 objects in it?

At first line of image should be like Array[9] why it is showing Array[0]

[image]

In second image array has 13 objects so it is showing Array[13] not Array[0]

Comment: Its an Array at index 0 with length 9 that is inside another Array

Comment: check `arrayname.length` instead of `arrayname[0].length`.

Comment: Question is too vauge. Provide more details.

Comment: at first line it should be like Array[9] why it is showing Array[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are logging the output of the array before you are adding objects to your array. Something like

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr);
arr.push({}); //pushing blank obj
```

Here, executing this code will result in `Array[0]` but it does hold your object and will return a `length` of `1` if you try `arr.length`.

This might also happen if you are having some sort of Async function which pushes item to your array, which will result in the same thing. For example,

```
var a = [];
setTimeout(function(){
  a.push({});
  a.push({});
}, 1000);
console.log(a);
```

I think, this behavior is intentional, where Chrome wants to show that initially, your Array was empty, later on, items were pushed on runtime.